# distributed persistent durable message queue with least operations overhead for .net

Tags: .net, cluster-computing, message-queue, publish-subscribe, distributed

There are many options these days to run a durable distributed message queue :

- Kafka
- Rabbit MQ
- Active MQ
- queue on top of mongo DB
- many others...

I want to understand which one (including the ones not listed by me above) can offer pub-sub type of capabilities for a .net stack, while offering the least operations overhead for running in a cluster.

What I mean by least operations overhead is that, no manual action(like typing in admin cmds o balance cluster etc.) should be needed. 
Basically, I want something like ElasticSearch, where clustering and node management is extremely.

There are also many PAAS offerings like :

- SQS
- Kinesis
- many others...

I do not want to use a PAAS offering.

Is there any distributed persistent durable message queue, with the least operations overhead?

Comment: Have you looked at mqtt?

Comment: yeah I have looked at the likes of *MQs for e.g. rabbitMQ, ActiveMQs.
But getting to work in a cluster seems to be a big task.